# Node Js y React Js - Subir imagen local a una carpeta de del proyecto con react y node js

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

Estoy creando una app, en la cual deseo enviar una "subir" una imagen local a una carpeta de mi proyecto de Node Js, estoy lo realizo seleccionando la imagen desde un formulario en react js y envío la información mediante axios, sin embargo no me ha funcionado y recibo un error como el siguiente

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open'C:\Users\joshu_lmv4h9a\Documents\React_Proyects\cloudinary_gallery_app\backend\src\routes\files\imagen2.png

Lo he intentado de la siguiente forma, pero de nuevo, no funciona:

Esta es la configuración en Node Js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors  = require('cors');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')

const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();

require('dotenv').config(); 

// Other Settings
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(fileUpload())
app.use(express.static('files'))
```

La ruta con la cual intento guardar las imágenes:

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const newPath = __dirname + '/files/';
    const file = req.files.file;
    const filename = file.name;

    file.mv(`${newPath}${filename}`)
}
```

Finalmente el código en react:

- La información de la imagen la envío en form_data

  ```
   const Form = () => {
       const [form_data, set_form_data] = useState();

       const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
           e.preventDefault();
           await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/', form_data, {
              image_name: image_name,
              description: image_description
           })
       }

       const send_image = (files) => {
           const formData = new FormData();
           formData.append('file', files)
           set_form_data(formData)
           console.log(formData)
       }

       return (
           <Container>
               <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                   <input 
                       type="file" 
                       id="image_file"
                       onChange={(e) => {
                           send_image(e.target.files[0])
                       }}
                   />
                   <label htmlFor="image_file">
                       <span>Select Image</span>
                   </label>
                   <button>Save Image</button>
               </form>
       </Container>
   );
  }
  ```

Ésta es mi estructura de ficheros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Responderé a mi propia pregunta en caso de que a alguien se le presente el mismo problema, la solución radica en que debemos fijarnos bien en el mensaje de error open

> C:\Users\joshu_lmv4h9a\Documents\React_Proyects\cloudinary_gallery_app\backend\src\routes\files\imagen2.png

Por ejemplo, en dicho mensaje me indica que está esperando que la carpeta en la que se guardarán los archivos, en éste caso "files", se encuentre de tal forma (como nos indica en el mensaje) src\routes\files, con lo cual, lo único que procederíamos a realizar es cambiar la carpeta dentro de "routes", en pocas palabras que cumpla con la ruta indicada, por ejemplo en la imagen donde indico la estructura de ficheros, no cumple con la ruta que está esperando en el mensaje de error, ya que está como src\files\routes. Espero que se de ayuda. Saludos